# I need an explanation for the dereviation of a factor in the Two-Ray Model in Wikipedia

Tags: rf, radio, electromagnetic, propagation

In the Two-Ray model, I wish to understand how the marked factor in the attached picture has been derived.
source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-ray_ground-reflection_model

[image]

Is this factor the E field, and how was it derived?

Comment: What was the explanation given? What references doe the Wiki article link to that may answer your question?

Comment: There's no explanation for how this equation was derived.

Comment: And you have read all the references and further reading?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the details, but any time I see \$4\pi\$ I already know we are talking about steradians and a likely constant related to whether or not one is is just using \$r\$ or the surface area that \$r\$ generates. It's seen all over the place. For example, Newton famously failed to include \$4\pi\$ in his universal gravitation equation. And we all are paying for that mistake. Same applies to Gauss' Law vs Coulomb's. Can't say much about this case, though. I'm ignorant. But I have a strong suspicion about the denominator part, anyway.

Comment: I know it should be related to |E|^2 /ETAo= SQRT(PtGt/4*PI*R^2)

Comment: I recall my boss at Iris Systems told me about his microwave repeater failure in winter when a lower ground reflected loss from a body of water caused a stationary Ricean Fading loss out of phase to reduce the CNR of the received signal.  A deflector was added to block it.  Look up Ricean Fading loss. It may help. Is it 1/2sqrt(Gt)?

Comment: Rician loss https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rician_fading